# select rows from table where id=max

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have table that has several rows with the same `ProcessID` but different `ID`. How can I select rows with max `ID` and different `ProcessID` in a SQL query and Entity Framework?

My table:

```
ID     | ProcessID  | MESSAGE    | STATUS
-------+------------+------------+--------
100    | 100        | test       | 2
101    | 100        | test       | 2
102    | 100        | test       | 3
103    | 100        | test       | 4
104    | 104        | test       | 5
105    | 104        | test       | 6
106    | 104        | test       | 7
107    | 104        | test       | 8
108    | 104        | test       | 09
```

When search:

```
ID     | ProcessID  | MESSAGE    | STATUS
-------+------------+------------+---------    
103    | 100        | test       | 4
108    | 104        | test       | 09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT  ID, ProccessID, MESSAGE, STATUS 
FROM (SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessID ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework suggests you are using SQL Server.  Then you can use my favorite method, which doesn't use a subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by processid order by id desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = (from item in ctx.Processes
            group item by item.ProcessID into sub
            let maxId = sub.Max(x => x.ID)
            select new
            {
                ID = maxId,
                ProcessID = sub.Key,
                sub.Where(x => x.ID == maxId).First().MESSAGE,
                sub.Where(x => x.ID == maxId).First().STATUS
            }).ToList();

//or this variant
data = (from item in ctx.Processes
        join gr in (from temp in ctx.Processes
                    group temp by temp.ProcessID into sub
                    select sub.Max(x => x.ID))
        on item.ID equals gr
        select new
        {
            item.ID,
            item.ProcessID,
            item.MESSAGE,
            item.STATUS,
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple **group by** with max(id)

```
select max(id), processID, message, status   
from TableFoo  
group by processID
```

It should carry the message,status with the max(id)

Comment: sorry - my bad.  i didn't have a DB to test with, but indeed, outside of MySQL not having all select columns in group-by has indeterminate results.